# %s format is used to find address of a string

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
     char a[]="get organized learn c!";
     printf("%s",&a[2]);
}
```

I got the output:

```
t organized learn c!
```

it should give error because i used &  for %s

Comment: Why do you think you should get an error?

Comment: The `"%s"` format *expects* a pointer. A pointer to a zero-terminated string of `char` elements. Which is what you give as argument. Why do you think you should get an error?

Answer (score 4):

No, your code is behaving correctly.

- `a` is an array of type `char`. It is compatible with `char *`
- `a[2]` is a single `char`
- `&a[2]` is a `char *` which points to the third character in the array. It is equivalent to `a + 2`.

Answer (score 1):

It should not give an error - the printf in the code works correctly.

You cannot look at the address-of `&` operator alone, and decide that the result it produces is invalid, because the rest of the expression is important, too. In your case, `&` operator is applied to `a[2]`, so it takes the address of the third character in the string. This is valid, as long as your null-terminated string has at least two characters, which your string does.

```
get organized learn c!\0
^ ^                    ^
| |                    +- null terminator
| +---------------------- &a[2] points here
+------------------------ a, interpreted as a pointer, points here
```

As you can see, both `a` and `&a[2]` point to valid null-terminated C strings. In your case, strings overlap, but C does not prohibit it.

Comment: *the code works correctly.*: except for `void main()` ;-)

Comment: @chqrlie Right, there's always place in life for some healthy UB :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error is not where you expect:

- The prototype for `main` without arguments should be `int main(void)`
- For good style, `main` should return 0 explicitly.
- For a conversion specifier `%s`, `printf` expects a pointer to a null terminated string.   `&a[2]` is the address of the third byte in `a`, which is a valid `char` pointer into `a`, namely to the null terminated string `"t organized learnc!"`, no error here.

You could have written `a + 2` or `2 + a` or even `&2[a]` with the same exact meaning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
     char a[] = "get organized learn c!";
     printf("%s\n", &a[2]);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should `return 0` be `return EXIT_SUCCESS`?

Comment: @EdHeal: The behavior should be substantially the same: the return value from `main` handled as if `exit()` had been called with it as its `status` argument: *Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of `status` is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If the value of `status` is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.*